# Convergence in Probability of Infinite Sum of Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Suppose we have random variables, $\{Y_{in}\}_{i\leq n, n\in \mathbb{N}}$, such that
$$ Y_{in} \xrightarrow{p} 0, \text{ as $n \to \infty$}, $$
for all $i$. We also have that, for any fixed $n$, the random variables $Y_{1n}, Y_{2n}, \ldots, Y_{nn}$ are identically distributed (but **not** independent).

Is it true that
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_{in} \xrightarrow{p} 0, \text{ as $n \to \infty$ (?)} $$
I am unable to come up with a counterexample or proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega=[0,\,1)]$ with Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathbb P(B)=\lambda(B)$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. Set
$$
Y_{in}(\omega) = \begin{cases}n, & \frac{i-1}{n}\leq \omega <\frac{i}{n},\cr 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
Then for any $i\leq n$, 
$$
\mathbb P(Y_{in}=n)=\frac1n=1-\mathbb P(Y_{in}=0)
$$ 
and $Y_{in}\xrightarrow{p}0$ as $n\to\infty$ for any $i$.

But $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{in}=n$ for any $\omega\in\Omega$ and 
$$
\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{in} \to 1. 
$$
Moreover, this ratio equals to $1$ for any $n$, for any $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you / spasibo! :)
I hope I can ask a follow-up question. I am fairly new to rigorous probability theory. Do you think the result holds if there exists an $M$ such that
$$ \mathbb{P}(Y_{in} \leq M) = 1, $$
for all $i, n$?

Comment: If $|Y_{in}|$ are uniformly bounded, then sequence $\{Y_{1n}\}_{n\geq 1}$ is UI (uniformly integrable) and therefore $\mathbb E|Y_{in}|\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Then Markov inequality works: 
$$\mathbb P(|\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{in}| \geq \varepsilon) \leq \frac{\mathbb E(|\sum_{i=1}^n Y_{in}|)}{n\varepsilon} \leq \frac{nE|Y_{1n}|}{n\varepsilon} \to 0. 
$$